# Complicated Mysql Query on my website

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a situation in my current website which is basically a complicated Questioner having around 400 questions.

I have three table .

**1.Questions**.

```
ID , QID, Question_Text,Event_name
```

**2.Users**

```
ID , Name ,Event_name
```

**3.Answers**

```
ID, User_ID ,Question_ID , Answer_text
```

So now each user will have an unique answers for each questions in Answers table.

My problems starts here.
I updated new Questions in the Question table so The old users do not have answer in the answer table for the new question and hence my syatem is throwing error .

So I have to insert empty row into answers table for those users and those questions which do not exist in the answers table according to the Event .

Please help me write this query

My Attempt which failed

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `answers` inner join users on answers.user_id=users.id inner join questions on questions.id=answers.question_id
```

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting now?

Comment: and what u actually want to do? get rows for all users with (if) empty data on other tables? if so, why in your select-fields is only user_id?

Comment: why you need to insert empty row in questions and users table  where it is (user_id, question_id) defined as foreign key in answer table ?

Comment: I think I am not clear With my question , I will try to explain in a better way

Comment: i think when you add a question you could add new row for each user in answer table. Than if user answer you could update the empty row in answer table. Am i understand you correct?

Comment: @ganaa yes I have to insert new row for the new question for the existing user ,

Comment: @ganaa i got it wht you told, but what its need ? empty row make any sense ?

Comment: i thought that this is one kind of exam. Empty row is used for scoring the answer.  If no need empty row when you answer the question possible to add answer to the answer table.

Comment: @HiteshMundra The App has some functionality like export to PDF and Ecel and now they have some embeded static questions , So if those question has no row in the answer table the Elloquent returns an error . This is why I have to insert  row for the old users

Answer (score 0):

It would be drastic effect, if you have 10000 users and for each question 10000 records would be inserted. And with the time users would be increase.

If you can change schema then it could be an alternative way. for example- your Answer table look like- **Answer(ID, User_ID as STRING, Question_ID**),
**Answer_text(Answer_id, User_id, Answer_text)**. 
In *Answer* table user_id column is string type column which have comma separated string of user_id (logically represent as foreign key by not actually). And in *Answer_text* table the user_id column is foreign key of *Users* table. When you get the record you can break the string by comma and get each user_id in array form.

Now when you add a question then by default all users id are concated in string form and inserted. Only 1 record is inserted. and when any user answer, you can insert into Answer_text table.

Comment: bro its already been used by around 85 people doing such drastic change now will not be possible, Changing schema means Updating huge number of lines in the code . :(

Comment: It is a good idea indeed and I think that you can easily create the new table and with a couple of queries migrate data from old to new structure.